# Finding possible positions of a polygon within a refined area

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In QGIS, I have a geometry (polygon) of a given size and would like to asses all possible placements of this geometry within the refined area. Does anyone have an idea how to do this? If I should be using Python to calculate all possible positions, or if there is another way? Calculation of different geometries must be different to another calculation with a minimum Spacing in X,Y or angle. This can maybe be done by including a list of Y values list of X values and List of angles by defining a area of interest.

Do you know a good method for solving such a problem?

In the picture I show one possible placement of the geometry (yellow) within the refined area (red). The geometry should both be able to be moved, and be rotated.

[image]

Comment: Nice question, but can you be more specific regarding the *all possible placements of this geometry within the refined area*. Do you want to access how many times the geometry fits into the refined area? What is the distance or step between each try? Can each try start from the beginning or better to follow a certain principle? Is it allowed to rotate the feature or the refined area?

Comment: There's an infinite number of possibe positions; how do you determine the "correct" one?

Comment: Simply finding *one* way of placing a polygon inside another polygon is a computationally hard problem. And you want to find all the ways?

Comment: Thank you for the comments.
I was thinking to do the computations with a defined spacing, and a defined minimum change in angle. So that there will not be multiple solutions being really close to the others.